# Trying to implement carousel same as airbnb.com

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to learn bootstrap and I started to play around airbnb.com html file. I did ctrl-s to get all the files and open html file to edit it.  I got the airbnb files because I like the way that images are shuffling (can we call this carousel?)

So, first thing I did, I changed the pictures that are shown on home page.  The first image changed, but surprise, when I do so, images stop to shuffle.  Even if I click on the right arrow (you can check on airbnb.com), images are not changing.

The code with the images is the following.  I can't see anything related with shuffling images or anything :

```
<div id="hero" style="display:block;" data-native-currency="CAD" class="search_intro">
  <ul class="unstyled" id="slideshow">
      <li class="" data-slide-type="search_intro" data-bg-opacity="1" style="display: block;">
      <img alt="Maison pittoresque" src="./prototype_files/25681-86e324d87449b1f07afd358cc62bbbb8.jpg" height="700" width="1600">
        <div class="caption">
            <button class="wish_list_button not_saved heart btn gray large" data-hosting_id="25681" title="Enregistrez cette annonce pour plus tard." data-name="Maison pittoresque" data-address="Munster, France">
              <i class="icon icon-product-wishlist pink"></i>
            </button>
          <a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/25681"><img alt="25681-3f7484e66def17ef287de5c686e497a2" height="40" src="./prototype_files/25681-3f7484e66def17ef287de5c686e497a2.jpg" width="40"></a>
          <p><strong><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/25681">Maison pittoresque</a></strong>
            <br><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/25681">Munster, France</a> -
                  <span class="price" data-price="80.0427">$83 CAD</span></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li data-slide-type="search_intro" data-bg-opacity="1" class="active">
      <img alt="Superbe villa sur la plage" height="700" width="1600" src="./prototype_files/387153-b6473710c2cb9ec734cb06bf9d90bdd8.jpg">
        <div class="caption" style="display: block;">
            <button class="wish_list_button not_saved heart btn gray large" data-hosting_id="387153" title="Enregistrez cette annonce pour plus tard." data-name="Superbe villa sur la plage" data-address="Bali, Indonésie">
              <i class="icon icon-product-wishlist pink"></i>
            </button>
          <a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/387153"><img alt="387153-098c2c9ac018937ef05a8b7079c4149e" height="40" src="./prototype_files/387153-098c2c9ac018937ef05a8b7079c4149e.jpg" width="40"></a>
          <p><strong><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/387153">Superbe villa sur la plage</a></strong>
            <br><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/387153">Bali, Indonésie</a> -
                  <span class="price" data-price="171.0">$177 CAD</span></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li data-slide-type="search_intro" data-bg-opacity="1">
      <img alt="Cabane d&#39;intérieur en Allemagne" height="700" width="1600" src="./prototype_files/511605-333786588d7d46abb7949afeb3dbddfb.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
            <button class="wish_list_button not_saved heart btn gray large" data-hosting_id="511605" title="Enregistrez cette annonce pour plus tard." data-name="Cabane d&#39;intérieur en Allemagne" data-address="Constance, Allemagne">
              <i class="icon icon-product-wishlist pink"></i>
            </button>
          <a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/511605"><img alt="511605-3b6430731c0469cb219253433f5f975d" height="40" src="./prototype_files/511605-3b6430731c0469cb219253433f5f975d.jpg" width="40"></a>
          <p><strong><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/511605">Cabane d'intérieur en Allemagne</a></strong>
            <br><a href="https://fr.airbnb.ca/rooms/511605">Constance, Allemagne</a> -
                  <span class="price" data-price="85.3789">$88 CAD</span></p>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

I also played with carousel demo from bootstrap website, but I don't like it.  SO, my question is :

How to do airbnb.com carousel style?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a great slider use [skitter slider](http://www.skitter-slider.net/).
It has also great customization.

Comment: thank you for the tip, but it isn't the carousel style that I am looking for.